# urllib2.urlopen crashing for unknown reason

Tags: python, urllib2

I have some code which is very similar to code used here:

https://github.com/jeysonmc/python-google-speech-scripts/blob/master/stt_google.py

Here is my code:

```
    f = open(filename, 'rb')
    speech = f.read()
    f.close()


    LANG_CODE = 'en-US'  # Language to use
    GOOGLE_SPEECH_URL = 'https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&pfilter=2&lang=%s&maxresults=6' % (LANG_CODE)


    f = open(filename, 'rb')
    flac_cont = f.read()
    f.close()

    hrs = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.63 Safari/535.7", 
       'Content-type': 'audio/x-flac; rate=16000'}  

    req = urllib2.Request(GOOGLE_SPEECH_URL, data=flac_cont, headers=hrs)
    print "Sending request to Google TTS"
    p = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    response = p.read()
    print "response", response
    res = eval(response)['hypotheses']
```

It seems to get stuck on the `urllib2.urlopen(req)` line. It gives back this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google-speech.py", line 443, in <module>
    GoogleSpeech.text_from_speech(filename)
  File "google-speech.py", line 274, in text_from_speech
    p = urllib2.urlopen(req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

I'm not sure what the issue could be

EDIT: Added the end of my backtrace, which was missing earlier

Comment: I think you're missing the end of your traceback...

Comment: @MattDMo woops, added it

Comment: Is that the file designated by filename is FLAC encoded ?

Comment: Yes, it's FLAC encoded using the code from the website I linked to.

Answer (score 2):

If the error happens randomly, you can use a graceful retry algorithm, such as the one implemented here:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Retry

The idea is that, if for example the URL is currently not reachable, you don't keep retrying blindly, but increase the retry interval to allow the target location to recover, and backoff eventually if the URL cannot be opened at all.

If the error happens everytime, you have a different problem and should post the complete stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do to overcome this problem:

```
while True:
    try:
        p = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        break
     except Exception as e:
        print(e, 'Trying again...')
```

Comment: what is e here?

Comment: `e` is the Exception object that has been raised.